# ¿Cómo comparar un valor con múltiples valores en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo en **Javascript** una condicional el problema es poner muchos `||` y lineas innecesarias de código:

Tengo este codigo:

```
if(store.nroLicencia.valor=="Vacío"||store.nroLicencia.valor==""||store.nroLicencia.valor==null||store.nroLicencia.valor==undefined){
   valido = false
}
```

Hay forma de simplificar el condicional intente con algo así pero solo me valida el primer valor (`Vacío`).

```
if(store.nroLicencia.valor==("Vacío"||""||null||undefined)){
   valido = false
}
```

Alguien tiene alguna solución de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías introducir todas tus opciones dentro de un array y comprobar si la opción que buscas está en tu array mediante la función **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)**. Si el valor devuelto es mayor que -1 entonces significa que el valor está contenido en el array.

Aplicado a tu ejemplo sería:

```
var valores = ["Vacío","",null,undefined];

if(valores.indexOf(store.nroLicencia.valor) > -1){
   valido = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo más corto de esta forma:

```
if ( store.nroLicencia.valor == "Vacío" || !store.nroLicencia.valor ) {
  valido = false
}
```

La condicion: `!store.nroLicencia.valor` (con la `!` negación) te da `truthy` (verdadero) en los casos que estás comprobando: `''` (cadena vacía), `null` y `undefined`

Ejemplo visual:

```js
var valor_string_vacio = '';
var valor_null = null;
var valor_undefined = undefined;

if ( !valor_string_vacio ) {

  console.log( 'valor_string_vacio =', true );
}

if ( !valor_null ) {

  console.log( 'valor_null =',  true );
}

if ( !valor_undefined ) {

  console.log( 'valor_undefined =',  true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el doble comparador, no hay diferencia entre `null` y `undefined`:

```js
console.log(null==undefined);
```

En SQL existe la condición `IN`, que es más o menos lo que buscas. Eso no existe en Javascript ni en muchos otros lenguajes, pero podrías implementar algo parecido:

```js
function isIn(obj,...comp) {
  comp.indexOf(obj);
  
  return comp.indexOf(obj)!==-1
}



console.log(isIn(1,2,3));
console.log(isIn(1,2,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add () so it will work

```
item = 0
item_1 = 0
item_2 = 0


if(item === (item_1 && item_2)) {
    console.log("true");
}else{
    console.log("false");
};
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).